# Delete array elements from several arrays at once

Tags: python, numpy

I have arrays of centers, labels, and contours. I would like to delete elements with same indices from several arrays. I could achieve that with:

```
invalid = np.array([15,16,17])
centers = np.delete(centers, invalid, 0)
contours = np.delete(contours, invalid, 0)
labels = np.delete(labels, invalid, 0)
```

Is it possible to do this in one step if arrays are of same shape? What if shapes differ?

Comment: No, it is not possible.  `numpy.delete` accepts a **single** array as an argument, and returns a single array (a copy of the argument minus the removed items).  Can you perhaps merge the three arrays into a single 3-D one?  **Then** a single `delete` call would work as you wish.

Comment: Perhaps I could, but I'd have to "unpack" the array after deletion. The only reason I'd like to do deletion for all at once is because of code styling (it doesn't look "pretty" if I have 3 or 4 lines that are basically the same, only the operand is different). Thanks anyways.